# Spring OAuth2 Authentication with REST request

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-oauth2

**Background**

I followed [this tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v) in order to configure a OAuth2 server with spring-security-oauth2.

So far, it works like that :

- When the user tries to connect to the server, a plain old authentication dialog is displayed
- If correct credentials are given, the user is redirected to the default Spring's confirmation form.
- If the user chooses "Allow", the user is then redirected to whichever page I want with an authorization code that can be used to obtain the access token.

**SSCCE**

I placed this ready-to-run example [on my github account](https://github.com/ArnaudDenoyelle/sscce-spring-oauth2) (which is more or less the code that is given by the tutorial)

Clone with :

```
git clone https://github.com/ArnaudDenoyelle/sscce-spring-oauth2.git
```

Execute with :

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Then navigate to :

```
http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://example.com
```

Authenticate with :

```
-user : user
-password : password
```

**Problem**

Now, I would like to change the behavior :

- I would prefer a login/password form instead of the plain old authentication dialog.
- I don't want the second step which asks the user for authorization : I just want to get an access token.

So far, I can do it with the following steps :

- The user inputs its credentials in a custom form.
- I send a GET request to `http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://example.com`
- I get an **HTML response** (which is the confirmation form) but don't really care about it provided that it is an HTTP 200. It also provides me with some cookies that are necessary for the next step.
- I send a POST request to `http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize` with the same body parameters that are sent by the default spring's confirmation form :

  - user_oauth_approval = true
  - scope.openid = true

It works : the user is redirected to the page that I want (in this case : http://example.com?code=$authorization_code$ )

**The question**

All I want is actually to get rid of the Spring's confirmation form. It is useless in my case : I just want to get an access token for the current session, not permanently authorize a client to access private resources. Is there a configuration for that?

Relevant code is :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthserverApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthserverApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("acme")
                    .secret("acmesecret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password").scopes("openid");
        }

    }
}
```